# laravel cashier braintree BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, braintree, laravel-cashier

I'm on laravel tinker.
Utilizador means User in English.
When I do `Utilizador::all()->last()->subscribed('main')` I get:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::valid()'

Don't know why.
When I do `Utilizador::all()` I get all users and when I do `Subscription::all()` I get all subscriptions from the database. So my models seem to be working.
I also have a Utilizadores->subscription relationship and vice-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also have a Utilizadores->subscription relationship and vice-versa

Remove relationships between `User` and `Subscription` models. These relationships are already defined in the `Billable` trait and `Subscription` model.

Comment: Why can't I have this relationship?

Comment: @alexandre1985 look into the source code of `Billable` trait and `Subscription` model. These relationships are already defined.

Comment: Thank you, it did work. I noticed that the relationship between `User` and `Subscription` is set out-of-the-box through $user->subscriptions